# Trying to ask a user to provide a set of numbers, then have program determine if the numbers are in ascending order or not?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to create a program that asks the user for a set of numbers, first asking for the quantity of numbers, then having them input all the numbers. The program then checks the numbers, and determines whether or not the numbers given are in ascending order or not. Then, simply print out "yes ascending" or "no not ascending" and print out the array on one line..So far, my code will just always say that "yes, this is an increasing array!" Please look below for my code. Thanks in advance!..

tested: 1 2 3 4 5 6 --> pass
        1 3 5 2 4 6 --> fail (still says it is an ascending array)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isAscending(int arr[], int size)
{
        for (int i=0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
                if (arr[i] > arr[i+1])
                {
                        return false;
                }
        }
        return true;
}

int main()
{
        int arraysize = 0;
        string numbers;

        cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << endl;
        cin >> arraysize;
        if (arraysize < 1)
        {
                cout << "ERROR: you entered an incorrect value for the array size!" << endl;
        }

        cout << "Enter the numbers in the array, separated by a space, and press enter: " << endl;
        numbers += ' ' + numbers;
        cin >> numbers;

        int arr[arraysize];
        if ( isAscending(arr, arraysize))
        {
                cout << "This IS an increasing array!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
                cout << "This is NOT an ascending array!" << endl;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < arraysize - 1; i++)
        {
                cout << arr[i];
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `isAscending`, `return true;` is inside the loop. The loop never makes more than one iteration. So you only ever compare first and second element and make the decision based solely on those.

Comment: But it's worse than that. You pass `arr` to `isAscending` - but you never actually inititalize `arr`. You compare random garbage with other random garbage.

Comment: `int arr[arraysize];` isn't valid C++, just so you know.

Comment: If int arr[arraysize]; is not valid, could you let me know what the proper way of initializing an array with size of my variable arraysize, that would be most helpful!

Comment: Read up on `std::vector` and use that.

Comment: You're trying to do several new things at once: dynamic arrays, user input, testing whether an array is increasing. Tackle them one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading in "numbers", which you created as type String.

```
cout << "Enter the numbers in the array, separated by a space, and press enter: " << endl;
numbers += ' ' + numbers;
cin >> numbers;
```

Your numbers+= line isn't doing anything except adding a space to your numbers string before your cin happens... I know what you're trying to accomplish, and that won't do it.

Then you're suddenly making an array which, without initializing is filled with garbage, and immediately running isAscending on it:

```
int arr[arraysize];
if ( isAscending(arr, arraysize)){....}
```

I advise you declare your array before receiving input, read the input line and process it into INTEGERS, and then add each integer to your array. Here is a (crude) correction of the first section of code in your main that just reads in whitespace separated integers and fills the array with them:

```
 int main(){
    int arraysize = 0;
    int number = 0;

    cout << "Enter the size of the array: " << endl;
    cin >> arraysize;
    if (arraysize < 1) // you should really have this loop until you get correct input
    { cout << "ERROR: you entered an incorrect value for the array size!" << endl; }
    int* arr = new int[arraysize];
    cout << "Enter the numbers in the array, separated by a space, and press enter: " << endl;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < arraysize){
        cin >> number;
        arr[i] = number;
        i++;
    };

    if ( isAscending(arr, arraysize)){ cout << "This IS an increasing array!" << endl; }
    else{ cout << "This is NOT an ascending array!" << endl;}
    for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++){
        cout << arr[i];
        if( (i+1) == arraysize){ cout << ". ";}
        else cout << ", ";
    }
 return 0;
 }
```

If you're going to whine about somebody giving partial answers that only address the asker's question, maybe you should take the time to write something yourself.

Comment: Please fix the constant size array being given a non-const size in your answer as well, as Jonathan Potter pointed out.

Comment: It's not a solution I would use, I was just trying to point out some of their mistakes so they could get a better understanding of some of the missteps. Feel free to spend your own time writing a fully correct answer; I did specify that my answer was CRUDE. @namfuak

Comment: Thank you for the insight!I will try to correct my code based on the advice given to me, and will update accordingly when I do so..

Comment: I did realize just earlier that the numbers += was not doing what I wanted. I had the program print out numbers as a test step and it would only print the first number. Hopefully with the help provided, I will be able to fix that.

Comment: @Joseph When I fixed the array declaration, I also fixed your array printing for-loop that you had at the end of your main. Basically the full code I posted does everything you said you needed, it's just that in my initial answer I was trying to guide you to the answer rather than give it.